# extracting only the specified value from text using python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spacy, data-extraction

I have a text file containing data as given below. I have to extract all lines containing signed

```
The document was signed on July 12

The document was signed by Charlie

This document was assigned to John

The document was preassigned to Amanda
```

Expected output:

```
The document was signed on July 12

The document was signed by Charlie
```

If I am using:

```
for line in file:
    if "signed" in line:
        print (line)
```

It is printing all the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done by using a word boundary `\b`. \bsigned will match signed, but not assigned.

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/9)

You can use `re.search(line, ".*\bsigned.*")`

Comment: Thank you! I am new to regex. I studied about word boundary but it did not strike to my mind. Thank you again!

Comment: yes it is similar to the duplicate link which you posted but I would not have solved it by referring that example as I am new regex